# Decimal to binary conversion (8 bit) in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I've been working on an assignment and so far this is what i've gotten.

```
int n, c;

printf("Enter a decimal\n");
scanf_s("%d", &n);

printf("%d in binary is: ", n);

for (c = 7; c >= 0; c--)
{

    if (n >= 1)
        printf("1");
        n = n - 1;
    else (n < 1)
        printf("0");
        n = n / 2;
}
```

I'm new to code and am struggling to figure out where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? Does it work or not?

Comment: Which bit is the first one that you want to print?  That will tell you how to start your for loop.

Comment: Is there missing `{` braces `}` or poor indentation?

Comment: Post the compiler's error message to add clarity here.

Answer (score 0):

```
void printbin(unsigned char val)
{
    for(unsigned char i = 0x80; i; i >>= 1)
        printf("%c", val & i ? '1' : '0');
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a bitmask to test if a bit is set. To construct a bitmask one could use bit-shifting:

```
1 << 0  // shift 1 0 bits to the left: 0b00000001
1 << 1  // shift 1 0 bits to the left: 0b00000010
1 << 2  // shift 1 0 bits to the left: 0b00000100
1 << 3  // shift 1 0 bits to the left: 0b00001000
1 << 4  // shift 1 0 bits to the left: 0b00010000
1 << 5  // shift 1 0 bits to the left: 0b00100000
1 << 6  // shift 1 0 bits to the left: 0b01000000
1 << 7  // shift 1 0 bits to the left: 0b10000000
```

Then you can use that values to test if a specific bit is set using the bitwise-and operator:

```
value & (1 << 4)  // evaluates to true if bit 5 is set.
                  // counted 1-based from the right.
```

To use that to output a 8-bit value:

```
char unsigned value = 42;  // an 8-bit value

for (int bit = 8; bit; --bit) {  // count from 8 to 1
    putchar(value & (1 << (bit - 1)) ? '1' : '0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know that for conversion from decimal to binary we divide the decimal number repeatedly by 2 and store the reminder and multiply it with the place value so for that we will initialize three variables rem(for storing the reminder) bin(for updating the binary value) place( for getting the place value)

Here is the code for converting decimal to binary value

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
      {
         int num,bin=0,place=1,rem;
         printf("Enter the number\n");
         scanf("%d",&num);

         while(num>0)
         {
             rem =num%2;    //Returns the reminder by dividing the number with 2
    num =num/2;     //Returns the integer value after dividing the number by 2
    bin += place*rem;  //Store the binary value
    place *= 10;
}
printf("The binary number is %d",bin);
```

}